# Generate .pdfs with dynamic data on AngularJS or Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, excel, pdf

I have a CRUD module and I want to show a filterable, sortable view which I have created already. I want a technique or module or library that can fill up the sample data from DB to Microsoft Excel Sheet or .csv format.

Now, I am thinking about using a client side Angular-based solution as that way I would be able to instantly modify data (filter/sort) and then save it as pdf.

Or is it better to use server-side .pdf generation?

I am using MEAN stack on Node.js to create the webapp.

Comment: There are libraries for all the scenarios you mentioned.

Comment: No but I wanted to know which solution would be better for my scenario. Client side one or server side one. Does this depend on any other factors, if yes i'll paste them here

Comment: `better` is very subjective. CSV in client is fairly trivial but certainly isn't as user friendly for some...try a few out...recommendations like this are off topic here

Answer (score 0):

There are client side pdf generators that you can submit generated HTML on the through an ajax / http post and get a pdf file back. http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/  If you do server side then you can save it for later download without having to have it regenerated. I would say server side is the better route.

http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/

Answer (score 0):

If you need a pdf, the `pdfkit` module may work on the server or client with browserify.